# How to center and overlay image (on top of streaming webcam)

Tags: html, css

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                let selectedDeviceId;
                const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserBarcodeReader()
                codeReader.getVideoInputDevices()
                    .then((videoInputDevices) => {
                        const sourceSelect = document.getElementById('sourceSelect')
                        selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
    
                            codeReader.decodeFromInputVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, 'video').then((result) => {
           window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com'
                            }).catch((err) => {
           window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com'
                            })
    
                    })
            })
```

```css
html,body {
     margin:0;
    }
    body {
     padding:45px 0;
     background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/A9J4iWz.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <video id="video" width="100%" height="100%"></video>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pastebin.com/raw/STztkMyB"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

This page will stream a live video from your webcam.

I added this code to make an image overlay on top of the video, but I'm not sure why it isn't working:

```
body {
    padding:45px 0;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/A9J4iWz.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I've also tried adding z-index to the background image, but that didn't work.

What's causing the video to always show up on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the `body` to show in front of the content within it. The `body` element is not meant to act this way. What you should do is add your image to the page as its own element, then overlay it on top of your video, like so:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <video id="video"></video>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A9J4iWz.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

.wrap {
  position:relative;
}

video {
  background-color: blue;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:15;
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:25;
  text-align:center;
}

img {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You can play with your vertical and horizontal positioning to fit what you'd like to achieve. Here is a link to a fiddle which demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/2fu5woe3/2/